# ¿Select por defecto, dependiendo valor devuelvo en MySQL?

Tags: html, mysql, css, xhtml

Buenas tardes tengo el siguiente código:

```
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Centro de formación: </label>
          <select class="form-control" name="centroformacion" selected="Centro de Electricidad y Automatización Industrial">
            <option value="Centro Agropecuario de Buga">Centro Agropecuario de Buga</option>
            <option value="Centro Latinoamericano de Especies Menores">Centro Latinoamericano de Especies Menores</option>
            <option value="Centro de Electricidad y Automatización Industrial">Centro de Electricidad y Automatización Industrial</option>
            <option value="Centro de la Construcción">Centro de la Construcción</option>
            <option value="Centro de Diseño Tecnológico Industrial">Centro de Diseño Tecnológico Industrial</option>
            <option value="Centro Nacional de Asistencia Técnica  a la Industria - Astin">Centro Nacional de Asistencia Técnica  a la Industria - Astin</option>
            <option value="Centro de Gestión Tecnológica de Servicios">Centro de Gestión Tecnológica de Servicios</option>
            <option value="Centro de Tecnologías Agroindustriales">Centro de Tecnologías Agroindustriales</option>
            <option value="Centro de Biotecnología Industrial">Centro de Biotecnología Industrial</option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

¿Cómo coloco por defecto uno de ellos, dependiendo de lo que almacenó anteriormente a la hora del registro?

Comment: Como estás capturando los datos guardados anteriormente ?

Comment: no entiendo , quieres que salgo uno siempre que sea el mismo , o que en dependencia de algún valor  salga el que desees?

Comment: Claro hace parte de un formulario de registro, simplemente el select que seleccionó a la hora del registro se almacenó en la base de datos en una columna llamada centroformativo, entonces hay una sección de editar datos del usuario, en el cual aparece nuevamente el select pero quiero que se coloque automaticamente la opción que está guardada en MySQL.

Comment: Por que como sabrán el select carga la primera opción por defecto.

Comment: @AndrésJValencia estás usando php en tu vista? como lo estás haciendo?

Comment: Andres revisa al final de la respuesta que te agrege para poner valor por defecto en dependencia de lo que venga del servidor, dime si es lo que buscas

Answer (score 0):

mira si le colocas al select un id , ejemplo `<select id="mi_select"></select>` con las opciones dentro en el momento de guardar el formulario guardarías la opción seleccionada, y luego a la hora de mostrar el contenido revisarías que opción tenias seleccionada y pedirías el contenido para esa opción, seria así, en cuestión del ejemplo que te presento(utilizando jquery para que sea mas fácil):

```
var cual_seleccion=""
$('mi_select').change(function{  //con este evento actualizas valor cada vez que se seleccionan los datos
cual_seleccion = $('mi_select').val()  // almacenas en cual_seleccion el option del select

})
```

la variable **cual_seleccion** es la que guardas, ya que es la que te dice que option se selecciono para enviar a la base de datos, y después en dependencia de esta muestras los datos, supón que en una variable `data` vienen los datos que los pondrás en un `<p id="texto">`

```
if(data == "Opción 1"){
  $('#texto').empty()  // para quitar lo que aya anteriormente
  $('#texto').text("aquí dentro pones la información que saldrá en el p si es Opción 1")
}
else if(data == "Opción 2"){ ...  }
```

Si quieres un **valor por defecto** en dependencia de lo que tengas que mostrar seria así:

supón que cuentas con este `select`

```
 <select name="" id="sele"> 
   <option  value="a">A</option>
   <option value="b">B</option>
   <option value="c">C</option>
 </select>
```

en el `javascript` diría:

```
if(datos == "A"){  // datos es la información de mysql del servidor
    $("#sele").val('a')  
      // a es el id de la opción que deseo mostrar en el select
     // para poner los datos en alguna etiqueta te lo explique anteriormente
}
else if(datos == "B"){ $("#sele").val('b') } // igual b es el id de la opción
```